# Get the content in the middle of two HTML comments

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to get the HTML content which is in the middle of two HTML comments. see the code:

```
<p>hello</p>
<!-- Write your comments here -->
<p>hello</p>
<!-- another comment -->
```

In this example, i need to get the `<p>Hello</p>`, how can i do this? with Regex?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Same as without the comments. Or do they serve as *start* and *stop* indicators for  more than one node?

Comment: @Lain — How can you find content between two comments if there are no comments there?

Comment: ok, but, what is "same"? the comment not is a div, what i can do a innerHTML, i tried this.

Comment: @lain Yes, the comment start and stop in itself, this is the problem.

Comment: Leave this here on reg exp: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use childNodes and look at the Node type.

```js
function getNodesBetweenComments (wrapper) {
  var state = 0;
  return Array.from(wrapper.childNodes).filter(node => {
    if (node.nodeType === 8) state++;
    else return state === 1 && node.nodeType === 1
  })
}

const wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
console.log(getNodesBetweenComments(wrapper));


const wrapper2 = document.querySelector("#wrapper2");
console.log(getNodesBetweenComments(wrapper2));
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>hello</p>
  <!-- Write your comments here -->
  <p>hello</p>
  <!-- another comment -->
</div>

<div id="wrapper2">
  <p>hello</p>
  <!-- Write your comments here -->
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>there</p>
  <p>world</p>
  <!-- another comment -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath expression `//comment()` to find the comments, loop over them to find the ones you care about, then loop over the nodes from the first until you find the second.

```js
const comments = document.evaluate("//comment()", document);
let start;
let end;
while (comment = comments.iterateNext()) {
  if (comment.data.trim() === "Write your comments here") {
    start = comment;
  }
  if (comment.data.trim() === "another comment") {
    end = comment;
  }
}

let current = start.nextSibling;
let matches = [];
while (current !== end) {
  matches.push(current);
  current = current.nextSibling;
}

console.log(matches.map(node => node.textContent));
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
<!-- Write your comments here -->
<p>hello</p>
<!-- another comment -->
```

Note that this will break if the comments are not siblings, and I've not put any error handling in place.

Comment: Thanks, now i will adapt this code to run in other html contents, Thanks!